is it possible for gcov to annotate multiline statements
If we have a multiline statement, then the second, the third, etc. lines of this statement are reported as a white space.
For example, the constructor of class A with 4 integer parameters below is reported as one executed line followed by 2 white space ones.
       -:
       -:   18:
     223:   19:A::A(int param0,
       -:   20:     int param1,
       -:   21      int param2,
     223:   22:     int param3) :
...

Is it possible to make gcov emit something else for lines 20 and 21? I looked up the source code it seems that gcno/gcov do not collect information about multiline statements.
